# PHP and MySQL - Should I escape quotes, before bind variables in my queries?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, bind

Isn't it enough to just bind variables, using bindParam? Do we need to add slashes too? If I enter `mike's`, it goes into the database as `mike\\'s`.  How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to escape quotes before binding variables. Just make sure [magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) is disabled in your PHP configuration - this is probably what's causing the double escaping.

Comment: it is disabled.  it still adds the double quote :(  I also disabled it using set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);

Comment: What does your query look like? Use [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and no quotes should be required.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to escape it , i suggest to store your text as encoded utf8_encode/decode

Answer (score 0):

never mind, there was an extra mysql_escape_string somewhere in the code, which was causing the trouble :(